# How could I close InAppBrowser window when youtube video playing in phonegap ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I am working on iphone app development using cordova. I am trying to play a youtube video in `InAppBrowser`. In my scenario i have a rail of video thumbnails basically those are youtube videos. When we click on it, it needs to open a html page that contains a youtube player within `Phonegap` `InAppBrowser`, for that i have written like,

```
var ref = null;
function openVideo(Id)
{
    try {
         ref = window.open('video.html?id='+Id,'_blank','location=no'); 
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', LoadStop);
         ref.addEventListener('exit', Close);
    }
    catch (err)    
    {
        alert(err);
    }
}
function LoadStop(event) {
         //some code  
}
function Close(event) {
         ref.removeEventListener('loadstop', LoadStop);
         ref.removeEventListener('exit', Close);
}
```

and my video.html can have the following code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                body {
                    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="player"></div>
            <script>
              var tag = document.createElement('script'); 
              tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api"; 
              var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
              var player;
              function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() 
              { 
                 player = new YT.Player('player', 
              {  videoId: 'mQGTXhqVmCQ',
                 playerVars: { 'html5': 1},
                 events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady,'onStateChange':onPlayerStateChange              } 
    }); 
    } 

    function onPlayerReady(event) { 
    event.target.playVideo();
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    //needs to close in app browser here        
    window.close();
            }
    }
    function stopVideo() {
       player.stopVideo();
    }
     </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Here i am attaching screenshot,

[image]

Here what i am exactly facing problem is,

1, click on thumbnail opens video.html in InAppBroser

2, first video loads and video gets played in default iphone browser. After seeing video user will click on done button to come back to app.

3, But he sees the video.html page with youtube player on pause button and done button to back to app.

that means he needs to click to done buttons one in default player and another one in `InAppBrowser`. This will become user interface error. so i need to back the user to app when he clicks on done button in player. For that i need to able to close `InAppBrowser` window when youtube video is playing  but i am unable to get the reference of `InAppBrowser` since both are in different pages. I have tried window.close() in onstatechanged method youtube player. but it doesn't helped me. So how could i close `InAppBrowser` window when youtube video playing. Please guide me.